# Property of general vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V_n$ be a finite dimensional vector space with a norm without scalar product. Let $v_i$ $(i \in \{1,\dots,n\})$ be the base of $V_n$. For each vector $w \in V_n$ there exist $x \in E_n$ (Euclidean vector) such that $w = v(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i v_i$. Now let's have a sequence $(x^j)$ of Euclidean vectors $x_j \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Is it true the following:

> If $|x^j| \to \infty$ then $|v(x^j)| \to \infty$?

I would like to have this feature in some finite dimensional subspaces of Lebesgue spaces since I need it for some PDE analysis.

Comment: In finite dimensional vector spaces, all norms are equivalent. Choose for instance the $\ell^1$ norm and you are done. (Of course, the implied constant depends on the dimension in an a priori nonconstructive way.)

Comment: Lebesgue spaces are generally not finite dimensional. So the first half of your question does not seem to apply to the latter half of the question. Also, duplicating the $n$ for $V_n$ and for $(x^n)$ makes it hard to understand your intents. Please clarify.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Willie Wong, I clarified the question.